# killing a process from windows service

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, service

I am trying to keep the explorer.exe KILLED till an event.

I mean i have an xml file which i read from my windows service background worker. It waits for a value, till than the explorer.exe should not execute, its for security purpose.

I have tried till now :

```
While (True)
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument
            doc.Load("C:\Users\Alpha-Guy\AppData\Local\Packages\new-design_sa0tb4645bqbp\LocalState\metadata.xml")
            Dim list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("authenticated")
            var_auth = list(0).InnerText

            If var_auth = "0" Then
                Dim pro As Process
                pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")(0)
                If pro IsNot Nothing Then
                    pro.Kill()
                End If
            End If

            If var_auth = "1" Then
                Dim pro As Process
                pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")(0)
                If pro Is Nothing Then
                    Process.Start("c:\windows\explorer.exe")
                End If

                'Try
                '    pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")(0)
                'Catch ex As Exception
                '    Process.Start("c:\windows\explorer.exe")
                'End Try

            End If

        End While
```

this code is written in backgroundWorker's doWork() event.

my windows service will check for a value in xml database, if its 0 then it will check if explorer.exe is started or not, if yes than kill it.

if the value in xml file i found 1 than it will check if explorer.exe is started or not, if not than start it.

Problem : when i start the service, it kills the explorer.exe once, but explorer.exe open automatically and the service fails to kill it again.

Error : Accecss is denied.

if its some permission problem than how would it killed first time ??

Is there any problem with the code ???

Answer (score 2):

Make your program/service run as **Administrator** (or SYSTEM account, or smtg higher).
I think you can do it while 'installing' the service. Then you won't get that error.
Also run Visual Studio as Administrator if you don't want to get that error when running your service from Visual Studio.

I think this will help you. Good Luck!

Comment: i have managed to solve the above problem but now there is another problem raised..

now i want to start the explorer.exe process from my windows service.
i have read that the win service runs in session 0 while the explorer.exe and any other process runs in session 1 of windows. and i found some snippets that allows the process to start in session 1 from win service but they all were in C++. I want that snippet in VB.Net..

Any suggestion ???

Comment: i have tried Shell() function but no luck, nothing happens.. Please help me out..

Comment: @VivekKhatri try writing Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False before Process.Start This helps a lot.

Comment: @Jet : I tried, but nothing happens. may be its not working as windows service and explorer.exe runs in different sessions of windows.
have you tried on your machine ?? If yes, then pls share the snippet that you tried..

Comment: @VivekKhatri, I've updated answer. I've not tried it, but I think it'll help you :)